# New formula for counting semi-standard Young tableaux?

Tags: co.combinatorics

I have a proof that given a partition $\lambda=(\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_l)$
then the number of semi-standard Young tableaux (SSYT) of shape $\lambda$ with entries in $1,2,\dots, n$ is given by

$$\frac{1}{1!2!\cdots (n-1)!} \prod_{1\leq i\lt j\leq n} (\lambda_i-i)-(\lambda_j-j).$$
(We define $\lambda_j:=0$ if $j \gt l.$)

The product is also recognized as a Vandermonde determinant.

There are plenty of product formulas (over boxes in the tableau) 
and determinant formulas (but not in Vandermonde form, as far as I can tell) 
for the number of such SSYTs, but I have not seen a this particular one in the literature or in any article I've come across.

Is this formula known? Is this formula of any interest?

Comment: Probably known, sorry to disappoint. The number of semistandard Young tableaux of shape $\lambda$ is the value of the $\lambda$-Schur polynomial (which I consider as a polynomial in $n$ variables) at $\left(1,1,...,1\right)$ (because the $\lambda$-Schur polynomial is a generating function for semistandard Young tableaux of shape $\lambda$). But the value of the $\lambda$-Schur polynomial at $\left(1,1,...,1\right)$ is the dimension of the $\lambda$-Schur module of $\mathrm{GL}_n\mathbb C$ (since the $\lambda$-Schur polynomial is the character of this $\lambda$-Schur module). ...

Comment: ... By Weyl's character formula (Theorem 4.63 in Pavel Etingof's representation theory notes http://www-math.mit.edu/~etingof/replect.pdf ), the latter dimension is $\prod\limits_{1\leq i < j \leq n} \dfrac{\lambda_i - \lambda_j + j - i}{j-i} = \dfrac{1}{1! 2! ... \left(n-1\right)!} \prod\limits_{1\leq i < j \leq n} \left(\left(\lambda_i - i\right) - \left(\lambda_j - j\right)\right)$. Combining these observations, we get your formula. I suspect that some text has this more explicitly.

Comment: @darij grinberg: Yes, I am aware that it is the evaluation of the Schur polynomial at (1,...1). Do you have a reference? I'd love to put this identity at Wikipedia for example, since, in my humble opinion, this is a very straightforward way to compute these numbers.

Comment: @darij grinberg: Thank you very much!

Comment: That the $\lambda$-Schur polynomial is a generating function of the semistandard Young tableaux of shape $\lambda$ is a known fact, and combinatorialists usually use this as a definition of Schur polynomial. See, e. g., §4.4 of Sagan's "The Symmetric Group".

Comment: @darij grinberg: Sorry, was after the reference for the formula. Thanks again.

Comment: One reference is the case $q=1$ of *Enumerative Combinatorics*, vol. 2, (7.105) on page 375. This goes back to Littlewood and Richardson. See the discussion on page 403 of EC2.

Comment: I believe that this formula is due to MacMahon.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So, to answer this question, the formula is known. It is also (now) on the wikipedia page about Schur polynomials, so the next person will find it easily.

Answer (score 5):

I've finally found a place that gives this formula explicitly, without any need for piecing together or rewriting or taking limits using L'Hopital: [Martin Aigner, *A Course in Enumeration*, Springer 2007](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-540-39035-0), Section 8.5, formula (7) and the sentence that follows it.

I am wondering if anyone has ever given a bijective proof, though (after multiplying with the denominator).

Comment: That's a nice reference - it had some other chapters which happened to be relevant for a small project I might be working on